# Save video read from VirtualDubMod to file using command line only?

Tags: command-line, avi, avisynth, virtualdub

I want to compile several video clips using Avisynth on a server. I generate the .avs file and let VirtualDubMod read the file.

How do I save the video read from VirtualDubMod to an avi file using the command line only? If I open VirtualDubMod then I can choose save as but I am putting this on a server so no GUI will be available and it should be automatic.

EDIT:

After looking some more I found [this](http://avisynth.org/mediawiki/index.php?title=Save&redirect=no). Is this a recommended approach?

Comment: Yes, using the virtualdub scripting language is how you would control Virtualdub and probably virtualdubmod too.

Comment: @foxidrive I see, I will try it out and see if it works.